# Retrieve friends education_history from Facebook using koala Ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, koala, fb-graph

I would like to retrieve a users friend education_history, I am using koala gem and rubyonrails.

I have add the permission for getting a users friend education_history in my initalizer file for omniauth: `:scope => 'user_education_history,friends_education_history`

So far I can get the user friend :name and :id, but have no idea how to get a users friends education_history.

```
def add_friends
    facebook.get_connections("me", "friends").each do |hash|
      self.friends.where(:name => hash['name'], :uid => hash['id']).first_or_create
    end
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by using a fields key provide by koala, it more efficient and works fast:

```
def add_friends
    facebook.get_connections("me", "friends", :fields => "name, id, education").each do |hash|
      self.friends.where(:name => hash['name'], :uid => hash['id'], :highschool_name => hash['education'][0]['school']['name'], :graduateschool_name => hash['education'][1]['school']['name']).first_or_create
    end
  end
```